# Problem with Table view Android Java

Tags: android, tableview

I am trying to make a calculator with table view and I having a problem with the "=" button. I looking for something like a rowspan in HTML table, but I can´t find anything like that. I have no problem to make a solution in relative view but I have to make a solution with table view to.

Here is a picture of my GUI: http://www.mypicx.com/09062011/Calculator/

Here is a bit code in my XML file (this is only my code for just that button):

```
<TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/display"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:text="MC"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:text="MR"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:text="MS"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:text="M+"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:text="M-"/> 
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="DEL"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:text="CE"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="C"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:text="-/+"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:text="√"/>  
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sju"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="7"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/atta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="8"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="9"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="/"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:text="%"/>  
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fyra"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="4"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="5"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sex"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="6"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="*"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:text="1/x"/>    
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ett"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tva"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="2"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tre"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="3"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/minus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="-"/>

        </TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/lika"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="255"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClickResult"
                android:text="=" android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>   

          <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/noll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="0"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/komma"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="."/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/plus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="+"/> 

        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I think you can only do colspan. For rowspan you have to find out some workaround.